# Forcing meetings to record in Adobe connect

Tags: adobe-connect

I want to programmatically force meeting to get recorded in moodle.  There is an api available for that

```
    https://example.com/api/xml?action=meeting-feature-update&account-id=7&
feature-id=fidarchive&enable=false&feature-id=fid-archive-force&enable=true
```

I'm making call to it just before launching meeting in new window...but it is not working.It just dies when a call to it is made. Anyone having any experience with force recording feature of Adobe connect ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make force recording feature working, you must have dedicated hosting plan of adobe connect. This feature will not work on shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

The API call you're making there will turn on the force recording feature, but it may not have immediate effect. Meeting features such as that are cached and will have a 5-10 minute delay before taking effect.

It of course also requires sufficient (admin) permissions to have an effect. That setting will apply to *all* meetings hosted on that system, so be sure recording them all is what you want.

Posting the result you're receiving from that call might help if further troubleshooting is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Running this command I got:

```
<results>
<status code="invalid">
<invalid field="fidarchive" type="string" subcode="illegal-operation"/>
</status>
</results>
```